# How to add more blocks

Tags: xcode, swift

I tried adding `var square`, and all the things I did for `squareView`. But all I am getting is one box falling and the other just standing there. Is there an easier way to add another box which does the same action as `squareView`?

```
import UIKit

class interestViewController: UIViewController {
    var squareView: UIView!
    var square: UIView!
    var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
    var collision: UICollisionBehavior!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        squareView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
        square = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 100, 100, 100))

        squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        view.addSubview(square)
        view.addSubview(squareView)
        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)
        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)
        gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [squareView])
        gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [square])
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)
        collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [squareView])
        collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [square])
        collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
        animator.addBehavior(collision)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Watch the "Standford course Developing IOS 8 Apps with Swift", episode "12. Dynamic Animation" explains it all in detail.

Answer (score 0):

This code is sheer nonsense:

```
gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [squareView])
gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [square])
animator.addBehavior(gravity)
animator.addBehavior(gravity)
```

When you set the variable `gravity` to one behavior and to another behavior right in a row, the first behavior is just thrown out as if it never existed. So naturally when you get around to adding the behaviors, there is only one behavior to add: the one `gravity` that is left (which you then, even more nonsensically, add twice). So naturally only one block is animated.

Think of it more simply this way:

```
var x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
```

Now, what is the value of the variable `x`? If you think it is 0 *and* 1 *and* 2, you have not understood what a variable is.

Comment: yeah I realized that right after I posted do you know how to make both blocks animated? @matt

Comment: Yes I do, and so do you, now, if you think about my answer and how to change your code in accordance with it. I believe I have answered the question you _actually_ asked.

Comment: I got it thanks. How would I change the blocks to buttons? @matt